# Python - Problem closing threads

Tags: python

I'm using urllib2 to monitor a web socket. I have the following class which handles connecting to the site and receiving a response:

```
class Stream(Thread):

    def __init__(self, connectCallback=None, **kwargs):
        self.connectCallback = connectCallback
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.running = True

        while self.running:
            try:
                req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=self.headers)
                req.add_data(self.body)
                print "Stream connecting %s" % self
                self.connectCallback(self)
                f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                print "Stream connected %s" % self
                while 1:
                    if self.running:
                        print "data receiving"
                    else:
                        f.close()
                        break
                retry_time = self.retry_time
            except (urllib2.URLError, urllib2.HTTPError), e:
                print 'Exception: %s, retry in %f' % (e, retry_time)
                time.sleep(retry_time)
                retry_time *= 4.0
                if retry_time > self.max_retry:
                    retry_time = self.max_retry
            except Exception as err:
                print 'Exception: %s' % err

        print "Stream closed %s" % self

    def disconnect(self):
        print 'Disconnecting stream %s ' % self
        if self.running is False:
            return
        self.running = False
        self.join()
```

I want to be able to run more than one instance of my Stream class asynchronously. Here is my main class which instantiates the Streams:

```
class Consumer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.producer = self._open_stream()
            while 1:
                sleep(100)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.producer.disconnect()
            sys.exit()

    def onStreamConnect(self, instance):
        print "STREAM CONNECTED %s " % instance
        if getattr(self, 'new_producer', None):
            self.producer.disconnect()
        self.producer = instance

    def onTrackChange(self):
        print "TRACKS UPDATED"
        self.new_producer = self._open_stream()

    def _open_stream(self):
        s = Stream(onStreamConnect)
        s.start()
        return s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Consumer()
```

This works great when I have just one stream object, and the script closes cleanly. However, when I call my onTrackChange() method and establish more than one connection, the thread never closes and the run loop doesn't seem to end.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but why is it I can't shut down the stream objects?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not disconnecting your first producer in `onStreamConnect` since it is called from `_open_stream`. At this point the `self.new_producer` has not been assigned and the disconnect is not called until the next stream is added. Try this in a debugger or add more printouts to verify this.